# Domain controler on Azure VM

Tags: active-directory, virtual-machines

I want to replace my on premise server which contains a file server and DC and migrate it to Azure.

My on premise LAN is connected with a VPN gateway to my Azure Virtul Network.

Is it possible to have two DC servers on Azure (nothing on premise) and my on premise computers in the Azure VMs domain ?

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I think I will hear you and configure a DC on premise then replicate it to Azure. It's safer than my architecture. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but if the VPN connection goes down you will lose all domain functionalities in your office, including all authentication and even DNS resolution (which would also make your Internet unusable).

I'd strongly advise against that.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up - there is a reason MS did put a LOT of effort into local domain controllers for off central offices (i.e. a small sales office)... which is that relying on an out of location network (and that is what the internet is) can lead to significant downtime at times. Be careful what you wish for - this CAN come back biting.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes.

Is it advisable? Not really.

You should maintain at least one Domain Controller on premises in order to authenticate domain joined clients, and to provide services like DHCP and DNS in the event that the connection to Azure is unavailable.

You might also consider how you'll provide access to file and print services if the Azure connection is unavailable.